# Define range between two page breaks excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

i have an excel sheet that is separated by multiple page breaks - for each change in column C (column C represents specific ProjecID).

Each line of the table contains certain amount that has been spent. This amount is stored in column Q. (Note - for each project there can be multiple rows - amounts in column Q).

Depending if the subtotal amount (column Q) per project (column C) is <0 or >0, 
different operations should be performed within that range.

Question - How to loop through these ranges (between two page breaks) in order to check subtotal amount and perform appropriate operations on rows within each range?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

Following code deletes all previous page & then you can set up a Range,

```
Sub PageBreak()     
Dim CellRange As Range   
Dim TestCell As Range

Set CellRange = Selection   
For Each TestCell In CellRange
    ActiveSheet.Rows(TestCell.Row).PageBreak = xlPageBreakNone       
    If TestCell.Value <> TestCell.Offset(-1, 0).Value Then
        ActiveSheet.Rows(TestCell.Row).PageBreak = xlPageBreakManual         
    End If     
Next TestCell 
End Sub
```

NB: Select the cells from where you want to splits, don't count the Col headings, like if the Country name are in column D from rows 2 through 30, you would select the range in D3 through D30.

Answer (score 0):

try this. It removes page breaks from all sheets. Hope it helps.

```
       Sub PageBreak()

         Dim ws As Worksheet, tws As Worksheet
            Set tws = ActiveSheet
            For Each ws In Worksheets
                ws.Activate
                ActiveWindow.View = xlPageBreakNone
               Next ws
                tws.Activate
        End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, will prove useful in the future coding.